# Manipulating a power series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

By manipulating the power series expansion $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k, |x|<1$

Find a closed formula for $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k$

Not really sure how to go about this at all; I've seen the answer am having trouble finding out how to get there.

Comment: Hint: try computing the derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** think of differentiating. Since it's a power series within the open disc of convergence, differentiating the function amounts to differentiating termwise:

More detailed (place your mouse over the gray area to reveal its contents):

> If $$g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$ then for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$ we have $$g^\prime(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}.$$

Comment: Ah ok I understand now, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.